# Regex to match only if starts with and contains or ends with specific words

Tags: php, regex

I am wanting to match the following field names that start with `street` and end with `type` or `code` or both but not if the word after `street` is NOT `type` or `code`. For example:-

```
street_prefix_code
street_suffix_code
street_type_code
street_type_suffix
street_type
street_code
```

Match `street_type_code`, `street_type`, `street_code` but *NOT* `street_prefix_code`, `street_suffix_code`, `street_type_suffix`

Comment: Have you tried to write PHP code to perform your regular expression? If you have, please post it so that the community can help you with it. If you don't know how to write such code, have you tried searching the Internet for relevant tutorials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the following would do the trick:

`^street_(type|code)(.*_type|.*_code|)$`

It checks that the string begins with *street* followed by either *type* or *code* and ends after that or on another instance of *type* or *code*.

Comment: I like the simplicity. Again, as I am only matching not capturing I made a variation on this and is even fewer steps `/^(?:street).?(?:type|code).?(?:type|code|$)/i`